# Editor WYSIWYG com estilo de código

Tags: c#, html, css, asp.net-mvc, wysiwyg

Estou criando um site onde postarei alguns trechos de códigos (como se fosse um backup dos meus códigos), e para isso, estou utilizando ASP.NET MVC.

Está quase tudo pronto, o que está faltando é um editor WYSIWYG que atenda minhas necessidades.

Estou utilizando o TinyMCE. É muito bom, porém eu gostaria que o código final gerado pelo editor, ficasse parecido como um editor de códigos mesmo (com as cores de palavras reservadas e tudo mais).

Encontrei na internet, um [*framework* que parece ser muito bom](http://alexgorbatchev.com/SyntaxHighlighter/), mas eu não consegui utilizá-lo.

Que editor pode me ajudar?

Comment: Se ele é bom, faz o que quer, e aparentemente está sendo usado por várias pessoas, não seria melhor aprender como utilizá-lo ao invés de desistir dele? Para quais linguagens precisa?

Comment: tenta http://bluefish.openoffice.nl/download.html

Comment: @AndréSilveiraMachado posso estar enganado, mas o que isso tem a ver com o que ele pediu?

Comment: "Está quase tudo pronto, o que está faltando é um editor WYSIWYG que atenda minhas necessidades."

Comment: @AndréSilveiraMachado Eu vou analisar esse Framework. Nunca tinha escutado sobre ele.

Comment: @AndréSilveiraMachado leia o resto da pergunta.

Comment: @FlavioVissoto isto não é um *framewotk*, é um editor de texto.

Comment: @FlavioVissoto A resposta resolveu o seu problema? Acha que pode aceitá-la? Se não souber como faz, veja o [tour]. Isso ajudaria muito indicar que a solução foi útil para você e dar uma indicação que houve uma solução satisfatória. Também pode votar em qualquer pergunta ou resposta que achar útil no site todo.

Answer (score 2):

Pra não ficar sem uma resposta:

Algumas pessoas recomendam o [ColorCode](https://www.nuget.org/packages/ColorCode/). Ele não trabalha com muitas linguagens. Pelo que entendi ele teria que fazer isto no servidor, o que acho que não é o ideal na maioria dos casos.

Existe o [CodeMirror](http://weblogs.asp.net/jongalloway/using-codemirror-to-add-c-syntax-highlighting-to-an-editable-html-textarea?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397) só para C#. [Site oficial](https://codemirror.net/).

Mas eu acho que ficaria com o [SyntaxHighlighter](http://alexgorbatchev.com/SyntaxHighlighter/manual/brushes/csharp.html) que é o mais recomendado e usado por muitas pessoas. Quando não consegue usar, tem que ir atrás da solução, não desistir.

Comment: Eu vou olhar todos esses aí.  Não desisti... Eu apenas gostaria de saber se existe algum outro kit que faça a mesma coisa. Assim que eu testar os que você recomendou eu comento aqui o que achei deles é qual decidi utilizar.  Muito obrigado pela ajuda.

Comment: @FlavioVissoto veja também o [visual studio code](https://code.visualstudio.com/)

Comment: Bom dia senhores, consegui o que eu queria. Fiz algumas modificações no TinyMCE para ele trabalhar juntamente com o SyntaxHighlighter. Assim que eu finalizar e ter certeza que não deu mais nenhum problema postarei o código aqui. Mas ficou muito bom mesmo. Exatamente o que eu precisava.